# Apply a simple transform to turn a circle "inside-out" in an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I don't have clear terminology for what I am trying to do. So I will show the mathematical transform I am attempting to apply, a visual of what I am trying to do, and what I have managed so far.

For a set of coordinates `(r, θ)` inside a circle of radius `R` I want to apply the transform `T((r, θ)) --> (R-r, θ)`.

A visual example of a circular image that has been turned inside out:
[image]

So my thoughts where to find the indices of all the non-zero pixels, convert them to polar coordinates, apply the transform to the radii, reconvert to cartesian coordinates, and set the value of the pixels indicated by the new indices of `(x_{new},y_{new})` to the value of the old.

As follows:

```
# get he non-zero pixes indices
ori_y, ori_x = np.nonzero(circle_mask)

# offset to compensate for the location of the origin
x = ori_x - center_x
y = center_y - ori_y

# transform to polar coordinates
rs = (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5
thetas = np.arctan2(y, x)

# apply the transform to the r coordinates
rs = radius - rs

# convert back to cartesian coordinates
xs = rs * np.cos(thetas)
ys = rs * np.sin(thetas)

# round off and cast to int so they can be used for vector indexing
xs = np.round(xs).astype(int)
ys = np.round(ys).astype(int)

# return to original reference frame where origin is at top left
xs = xs + center_x
ys = center_y - ys

# instatiate a new image as destination
inverted = np.zeros_like(circle_mask)

# set new locations to appropriate values
inverted[ys, xs] = circle_mask[ori_y, ori_x]
```

The result:

[image]

I don't understand where the speckle pattern towards to perimeter of the circle came from. Can anyone help? My intuition is that it has something to do with rounding errors, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Have you tried `atan2()` in place of `arctan()` ?

Comment: Very good! I would never have considered that. In retrospect makes perfect sense.

Comment: I haven't done too much thinking about this, or any testing, but in general, when doing geometrical transforms such as this (and resizing etc), you need to take each point **in the output image** and work out what it will be from the input image. You have taken each point in the input image and worked out where it shows up in the output image but there may be some points in the output image for which you didn't get a value from the input image - so you get holes and missing bits. Try making your basic, empty output image red rather than black to see if there are unwritten red holes.

Comment: ... following on, I mean something like `inverted = np.zeros_like(circle_mask) + [255,0,0]`

Comment: I think you're right, that ultimately the problem is that my transform isn't well defined in my discrete plane as it would be in a (continuous) cartesian plane.